# Can I obtain a postgresql lock that prevents concurrent inserts for a portion of a table?

Tags: postgresql, locking

I have a join table `attendees` of `rooms` and `users` with an extra column that represents a randomly assigned string (from within a pool of strings).

**I want to prevent two users entering at the same time from accidentally getting assigned the same string** -- so I'd want User B to wait to look up the previous users in the room (and their assigned strings) until User A has completed inserting -- but I don't want to do a table lock since a row insertion for say `room_id = 12` doesn't affect an insertion for `room_id = 77`.

**I can't use a unique constraint to solve this**, since duplicate strings are possible in the case of a large number of users in a single room (the strings get reassigned evenly once all of them have been used once).*

My guess is doing something like

`SELECT room_id, user_id, random_string WHERE room_id = ? FOR UPDATE`

isn't going to help because it's not going to prevent User B from doing an insert -- and even if that `SELECT FOR UPDATE` prevented user B from doing the same call to read the rows corresponding to that room, what happens if both User A and User B are the first ones to join (and there aren't any rows for that `room_id` to lock)?

Would I use an advisory lock that's keyed on the `room_id`? Would that still help if I had multiple concurrent writes (e.g. User A should finish first, then User B, then User C)?

*Here's the example of why the strings aren't necessarily unique: say the pool of strings is `"red", "blue", "green"` -- the first three users that enter are each assigned one of them randomly, then the pool resets. The next three users are also assigned them randomly, so for the six users in the room, exactly two would have `"red"`, two `"blue"`, and two `"green"`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the essence of your problem. Can't you just assign a unique constraint on the field that contains this random string? In the case of constrain violation you assign another string.

Comment: Great idea, but the pool of strings is actually small and can be duplicated -- so the algorithm randomly distributes them evenly but in the case that there are a lot of users in the room, duplicates will be randomly distributed again.

Comment: What do you want to avoid then? In terms of values in DB what data is incorrect and violates the invariant you try to maintain? If the unique constraint is for the pair `(room_id, random_str)` so that it is not possible to assign the same unique string for the same room would it fill the bill?

Comment: Unique `(room_id, random_str)` won't work for the case of a `room_id` with `len(users) > len(pool_of_random_strings)`. Because the algorithm that assigns the strings *needs to know which strings have already been assigned in the room*, I'm trying to avoid the race condition where User B is fetching the list of attendees in the room while User A is in the process of joining -- that is, User B reads the rows for `room_id` before User A has finished doing an `INSERT`. I hope that makes more sense!

Comment: I don't understand the problem with the unique constraint.  One will win, the other will lose (with a unique constraint violation) and have to retry it with a different string.

Comment: Because (room_id, random_string) isn't necessarily unique. Say the pool of strings is three: (blue, white, red). Those strings get randomly assigned to the first 3 users that enter the room. The next three users that enter the room are also assigned strings _from the same pool_ so in that case you'd have exactly two users with blue, two with red, and two with white.

Comment: I still don't get what you want to achieve. It seems you want to serialize the assigning of colours to users. That is that the assigning for a room never happens in parallel and always one user after another. Is it the case?

Comment: If it is the case then it looks like [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You probably want to describe the initial issue you want to solve though this serialization can definitely be done

Comment: Yes, I want to serialize the assigning of colors to users. That's exactly it. Specifically: "I'm trying to avoid the race condition where User B is fetching the list of attendees in the room while User A is in the process of joining -- that is, User B reads the rows for room_id before User A has finished doing an INSERT."
*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a frustrating few days on SO I ended up getting a helpful response on Reddit that solves the problem:

Use a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` query on the **rooms** table, locking the row that corresponds to the room until the first user’s transaction completes.